# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}}=0$ in the metric space $X=\mathbb{C}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Given that $$s_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n},$$ I want to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{s_{n}}=0$$ in the metric space $X=\mathbb{C}.$ However, it seems to me that **Archimedean Property is not applicable to the case above**, because $s_{n}$ is not always positive for each $n$. Then, how can I do that?

Comment: By $C$ do you mean the complex numbers?

Comment: @Cbjork You're right. I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Then $\left | \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}-0\right |=\left | \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\right |=\left | \dfrac{1}{n}\right |<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need $s_n$ to be always positive; all you need is to show that for every real $\varepsilon>0$, $|s_n-0|<\varepsilon$ for all $n$ greater than some $N$.